# O que é None em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou usando o IDE online repl.it.

Uma parte do código tenha essa entrada do usuário

```
opcao = input(print('Digite:\n1- Acertei\n0-Errei\n\n='))
```

o que dá a saída:

> ```
> Digite:
> 1- Acertei
> 0-Errei
>
> =
> None
> ```

Não afeta a execução do código, minha dúvida é:

1. O que é o "None".
2. Como retirar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`None` é nada, é a falta de valor. No caso está imprimindo isso porque o resultado da função `print()` sempre é `None` porque ela é uma função que só faz uma ação e não gera um resultado válido.

Não é questão de retirar o `None`, tem que consertar o erro de programação. Não faz muito sentido colocar um [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) dentro de um [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Provavelmente o que você que é isto:

```
opcao = input('Digite:\n1 - Acertei\n0 - Errei\n\n = ')
print(opcao)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/b9ZVBS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Inputpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Input.py).

Estude as funções antes de usá-lo. Todas elas possuem documentação do que espera, o que faz e o que resulta. Por exemplo: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html, além dos *links* acima.

Comment: Tem que razão, era só retirar o print, 
Funcionou